# How Do I Get The Resource DLL Code Samples In The Windows SDKs To Compile And Run?

Tags: com, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, cluster-computing, resource-dll

I am currently trying to build a Resource DLL on on Windows Server 2003 and 2008. I am currently working with the Resource DLL code samples supplied with the Windows SDKs, and I can't get them to work.

On Windows Server 2008 I succeeded compiling the Windows 7 SDK ClipBook Server sample, but couldn't get it to properly work in the cluster. When I insert the resource as a resource type to the cluster using "cluster restype  /create /dll" it works, but the resource is listed with an unknown type instead of a ClipBook Server type, as I think it should have as it is the type defined in the Resource DLL's code.
I also succeed in creating a resource of that type, but I can never get it to go Online. I always get the error:

**System error 5079 has occurred (0x000013d7).
The specified node does not support a resource of this type. This may be due to version inconsistencies or due to the absence of the resource DLL on this node.**

And this is despite the fact that the resource is located on all the nodes in the cluster including the one I try to start the resource on.

On Windows Server 2003, I'm working with the Platform SDK version 5.2, and I can't even get the ClipBook Server Resource DLL code sample to compile. I always get **MIDL1001 Error saying that it cannot open the file cluscfgserver.idl**. I added the path of the file's location to the include path of the project. That didn't work. When I tried to hard-code the path of the file, I got several linker errors when trying to link with this file.

If anyone knows anything about any of these problems, I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Can you share me the code sample using which you created the Resource DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those examples are *old and busted*.  Here are a few things I had to go through to get the similar "File Share Sample" to work:

- Convert the project to x64 (supposedly 32 bit resources still work, but I haven't been able to verify that)
- Add the module definition file (.def) to the linker input property page so that the Startup function is exposed
- There were several spots in code where CompareString is used to check the resource type name and 0 is expected on success, but it actually returns `CSTR_EQUAL` (3).

  - This is probably why you get the "(Unknown Type)" name.
- To register the resource extension, cluster.exe won't accept spaces in the dll name, so in my case I had to use `cluster /REGADMINEXT:'FILESH~2.dll'`
- Only the Property Sheet extension interface is supported, everything else (context menu, wizards) has been removed as of Server 2008
- Check the extension DLL stdafx.cpp sources for the Resource Type "ClipBook Server". It should be "ClipBook Server Sample": `const WCHAR g_wszResourceTypeNames[] = L"ClipBook Server Sample\0"`